# Por qué no puedo subir una imagen en el Storage o public path Laravel , Request-> file retorna Null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Intento subir la foto de este modo

```
if($request->hasFile('photo')){
            request()->validate([
            'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,tiff,tif,raw,bmp,psd',
        ]);

           $file = $request->file('photo');
           $name = $request->get('email')."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();
           // $file-> move($url,$name);
           $file->move(public_path().'/imageuser/', $name);
        }
```

Pero al realizar un `dd($request->file('photo'));` me devuelve un valor Null, este es mi form desde donde realizo la subida de la foto

```
<form action="{{ route('CatelFoto.store') }}" method="POST" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{ $id }}" readonly="readonly">
            <p><h2><b>Subir Foto</b></h2></p>
            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('photo') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label form="photo">Foto: </label>
                    <input class="form-control-file" type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="{{ old('photo') }}" required><br>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Siguiente</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más probable es que se esté perdiendo el `enctype` al enviar el formulario, parece un error menor y simple pero creo que el tipo de comillas que usa no son las correctas.

Usted añade `enctype=”multipart/form-data”` para esto el navegador renderizará `enctype="”multipart/form-data”"` lo cuál es incorrecto,  así que, cambiando esas comillas por las comillas dobles "normales", corregirá el error.

**Etiqueta Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('CatelFoto.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Eso me pasa por utilizar el previsor de codigo :p